# What is a suitable sentence to use when asking for your eyeglasses prescription?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-request, sentence-choice

As an already existing patient returning to the optician's, how do you ask for your prescription history. Say, you've lost your optical prescription from your last visit to the optician's. How do you, in one sentence, ask for a new one?

Would you say something like: "Could I have my previous eyeglasses prescription?"?

or is this sentence confusing? (I'm not even sure if the  term "eyeglasses prescription" is the correct term to be using here; I don't know what the correct term would be when referring to your eye-test results from a previous visit to the optician's)

(I'm always looking to improve on my English; so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically it's known as a *refraction* by optometrists, but any one would understand if you asked for your previous eye test prescription or results.
So you could ask *"Would you please give me a copy of my last eye test results?"*
Note I have used "would" rather than "could" as it is asking them to actually do something rather than if it were possible for them to do it.